# Do SQL Native Client connections need to be reopened after a complete failure of the principal server in a mirrored env?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, sql-server-native-client

I have a connection string as below:

```
DRIVER=SQL NATIVE CLIENT;SERVER=TCP:NYAVDEVINTDCDB1,5550;
FAILOVER_PARTNER=TCP:NYAVDEVINTDCDB2,5550;DATABASE=DMINTDC;
TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;POOLING=TRUE;
```

Do SQL Native Clients using this connection String have to perform a reconnect when the `NYAVDEVINTDCDB1` server gets completely disconnected or loses connectivity from the network? If not, why do I get a

```
[SQL Native Client]Communication link failure
```

when this situation arises?

I am using SQL Server Standard Edition 9.00.3152.00 SP2

Answer (score 0):

Clients need to reconnect in the event of a failover.